# Laravel5 only shows default page in linux ... the same works in windows

Tags: php, linux, apache, laravel, virtualhost

Maybe I miss something small , but I really get lost in here.
I made a virtual host to tun laravel:
I've created file in etc/apache2/site-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  laravel5.local
DocumentRoot "/var/www/ProjectFiles/NewProjects/laravel/public"
<Directory "/var/www/ProjectFiles/NewProjects/laravel/public">
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in site-enabled this is enabled
In etc/hosts I've:
     127.0.0.1     laravel5.local

So:
     "laravel5.local"  shows laravel5 default page.
     "laravel5.local/index.php" shows the same.

The problem is that I've changed this page (welcome blade) 
And if I try this :
"localhost/ProjectFiles/NewProjects/Laravel/public/"
I see the change I've made

Please note that if I do :
    php artisan serve 
and try on "localhost:8000" I still do not see that change, so the problem 
should not be in a mistake made in the virtualhost.
And the strangest thing is that all this works perfect in Windows.
Thanks in advance

P.S. and php artisan route:clear do not help

Comment: In your `VirtualHost` section you wrote `/laravel/` with lower case `L` in the text with `localhost` you wrote it with upper case `L`. Make sure you have the right upper/lower case in Linux. Windows doesn't care about it but Linux does!

Comment: I feel so stupid ... thanks a lot :)

Comment: Posted an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your VirtualHost section you wrote `/laravel/` with lower case `L` in the text with localhost you wrote it with upper case `L`. Make sure you have the right upper/lower case in Linux.

Windows doesn't care about it but Linux does!